# React router not working in very basic way

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hi have implemented `react-router` in a very basic way.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import About from './pages/About';
import Home from './pages/Home';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className='App'>
        <Link to='/about'>About</Link>
        <Link to='/home'>Home</Link>

        <Switch>
          <Route to='/about' exact component={About}></Route>
          <Route to='/home' exact component={Home}></Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I am wondering why this basic setup is not working?

I use react-router-doc version `5.2.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you passed wrong prop on Route component.

Try to change

```
<Route to='/about' exact component={About}></Route>
```

to

```
<Route path='/about' exact component={About}></Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
```

and change this statement

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

to

```
import { Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```